# Creating a Postgres function that returns JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've created a query to return data as an array of objects and it works fine, but I can't get it working as a Postgres function so I can call it wihin other queries to return a column containing the array.

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
    'first_name', u.first_name,
    'last_name', u.last_name,
    'username', u.username,
    'photo', p.filename
)) friends
FROM events e
     INNER JOIN user_events ue ON ue.event_uid::uuid = e.uid
     INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = ue.user_uid::uuid
     INNER JOIN user_followers uf ON uf.user_uid::uuid = u.uid
     LEFT JOIN photographs p on p.uid = u.profile_photograph_uid::uuid
WHERE e.uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
AND uf.follower_uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
```

The function I have created is this, which when I add to a query it throws an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION friends_attending(event_uid uuid, user_uid uuid)
RETURNS TABLE
        (
            friends character

        )
language plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
            'first_name', u.first_name,
            'last_name', u.last_name,
            'username', u.username,
            'photo', p.filename
        )) friends
    FROM events e
             INNER JOIN user_events ue ON ue.event_uid::uuid = e.uid
             INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = ue.user_uid::uuid
             INNER JOIN user_followers uf ON uf.user_uid::uuid = u.uid
             LEFT JOIN photographs p on p.uid = u.profile_photograph_uid::uuid
    WHERE e.uid = $1
      AND uf.follower_uid = $2;
END;
$$;
```

I'm using this function in another query.

```
 friends_attending(e.uid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

The error returned is

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: character = uuid 
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 
Where: PL/pgSQL function friends_attending(uuid,uuid) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

I've tried adding type casts to various parts of the function but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `friends_attending(e.uid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)`

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it 2 minutes after posting this, typical!

I was missing a type cast on the final AND as well as needing to set the returned data as json.

Answer (score 0):

The returned data was set as 'character' instead of 'json' & the final clause in there WHERE needed to be cast as uuid.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION friends_attending(event_uid uuid, user_uid uuid)
RETURNS TABLE
        (
            friends json

        )
language plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
            'first_name', u.first_name,
            'last_name', u.last_name,
            'username', u.username,
            'photo', p.filename
        )) friends
    FROM events e
             INNER JOIN user_events ue ON ue.event_uid::uuid = e.uid
             INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = ue.user_uid::uuid
             INNER JOIN user_followers uf ON uf.user_uid::uuid = u.uid
             LEFT JOIN photographs p on p.uid = u.profile_photograph_uid::uuid
    WHERE e.uid = $1
      AND uf.follower_uid::uuid = $2;
END;
$$;
```